# How do I reset a file created by cmake each time cmake reconfigures/regenerates my Makefiles?

Tags: cmake, configuration

I have a `cmake` function I use to create targets with proper dependencies as defined by my projects `debian/control` files. This works beautifully.

Now, I want to create a `DOT` file to have a graphical representation of my dependencies. For that I create a "deps.dot" file as follow:

```
function(CreateTargets COMPONENT)
    [...]
    if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps.dot")
        file(WRITE
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps.dot"
                "digraph dependencies {\n")
    endif()
    foreach( DEP ${DEPENDS_LIST} )
        file(APPEND
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps.dot"
                "\"${ARG_PROJECT_NAME}\" [shape=box];\n...
                      ...\"${ARG_PROJECT_NAME}\" -> \"${DEP}\";\n")
    endforeach()
    [...]
endfunction()
```

The very first time I configure, it works as expected. It creates the file with `digraph dependencies {` and then adds said dependencies in the `foreach()` loop.

The second component to be added will not trigger the `file(WRITE ...` since the file already exists.

Now, when I make changes to my `CMakeLists.txt` or module files, it re-runs that function and... *unfortunately* it reapplies the `file(APPEND ...` without first doing the `file(WRITE ...`. The result is a completely invalid `DOT` file.

How do I know I have to rerun the `file(WRITE ...`?

My current solution is to rename the file at the end, when I generate the SVG file:

```
    file(APPEND "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps.dot" "}\n")

    # We change the name of the deps.dot file so next time the
    # configuration runs it generates a brand new file
    #
    file(RENAME
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps.dot"
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies.dot")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND dot -Tsvg ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies.dot
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependencies.svg")
```

This works assuming the configuration works properly. If an error occurs, the `deps.dot` file lingers and I get that error from `DOT` saying the file is not a valid graph.

Comment: Why do you ever check the file's existence? Just rewrite the file **unconditionally** each `cmake` invocation. If you do not want to rewrite the file when components are not changed, then you need to tell that CMake in form of some *dependency* (file-level). You may ask CMake to not rewrite the file if its content isn't changed. Just accumulate all content into some *variable*, and use `configure_file` for create a file which contains just a variable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I could use a variable and at the end create the file with a WRITE. I have multiple components, though (obviously?!) so that's why I do an APPEND. But using a variable is probably a much better idea